# Dynamic array in template class destructor crashing program

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, dynamic-arrays

I have a template class which contains a private, dynamic array of the template's type. In main I have a while loop that continues based on initial conditions input by the user and this all works fine (reading from/manipulating the array the whole time).

Then after the while loop ends, the array isn't used anymore. But my program still does my last 2 couts and text file writes, then runs a simple lambda function (which doesn't use the array or its class), but then crashes before finishing:

```
newFile.close();
return 0;
```

This doesn't actually take away any functionality but I can't figure out why it crashes instead of just ending, according to the debugger the program counter stops at the end of the array's destructor.

My queueType.h:

```
template<class Type>
class QueueType {
public:
    QueueType();
    ~QueueType();
    QueueType(const QueueType& other);
    Type& getFront() {return queueArray[front];}
    void reposition();
    void addElement(Type);
    bool isEmpty() const {return numElements == 0;}
    bool isFull() const {return SIZE == numElements;}
    void updateWaitTimes(Type*&, int&, int&);

    QueueType<Type>& operator=(const QueueType other);

    friend void swap(QueueType& first, QueueType& second) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first.front, second.front);
        swap(first.back, second.back);
        swap(first.numElements, second.numElements);
        swap(first.queueArray, second.queueArray);
    }
private:
    static const int SIZE = 25;
    int front, back, numElements;
    Type *queueArray;
};
```

I'm also implementing the rule of 3 (plus constructor shown) in this class as follows:

```
template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::QueueType() {
    queueArray = new Type[SIZE];
    front = back = numElements = 0;
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::~QueueType() {
    delete [] queueArray;
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::QueueType(const QueueType& other) {
    front = other.front;
    back = other.back;
    numElements = other.numElements;
    std::copy(other.queueArray, other.queueArray + SIZE, queueArray);
}

template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>& QueueType<Type>::operator=(const QueueType other) {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Using this main:

```
typedef void(*Action)();
void iterateQueue(Action action) {
    action();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QueueType<CustomerType> Line;
        while (... < ...) {
            //various functions operate on Line, which produce no problems
        }
    cout << ...
    newFile << ...
    iterateQueue([] () {cout << endl << "I'm a lambda function!" << endl;});
    cout << "this never prints";
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** code added

Comment: Please present code rather than *describing your code* in expanded English.

Comment: I show my destructor code and the code that doesn't run that is leftover in main, not sure what else is necessary to show with this problem =/

Comment: You should post a minimal sample that reproduces the problem. Otherwise the only answer is "you have a bug in your code".

Comment: Your copy constructor is utterly broken. Please do not use `new` and `delete` unless you're an expert. Use proper dynamic containers instead.

Comment: Hhmm I got the copy/assignment setup from an article on rule of 3 o_O tips on fixing? It's been compiling fine on NetBeans for me somehow, just crashing after running

Comment: Added some couts to copy constructor, operator =, and destructor and apparently the only of those that's ever called is the destructor (in the very end)

Comment: Why are you swapping your queueArray members in your assignment operator?

Comment: OK.  After looking at the assignment operator, it seems that it will work, provided that the copy constructor isn't broken, which it looks like it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is wrong:

```
template<class Type>
QueueType<Type>::QueueType(const QueueType& other) {
    front = other.front;
    back = other.back;
    numElements = other.numElements;
    std::copy(other.queueArray, other.queueArray + SIZE, queueArray);
}
```

You are not allocating the queueArray for the current object.  Try this:

```
 template<class Type>
 QueueType<Type>::QueueType(const QueueType& other) : 
                            queueArray(new Type[SIZE]),
                            front(other.front), 
                            back(other.back), 
                            numElements(other.numElements)


{
    std::copy(other.queueArray, other.queueArray + SIZE, queueArray);
}
```

Comment: That is the problem... and a better fix would be to use `std::vector`.  Currently it's possible to leak `queueArray` if the `Type` copy constructor throws.

Comment: Thanks this does make sense with me not originally allocating heap space for the new array, but I changed it and still crashes after it runs? Using cout's I see that copy constructor and overloaded = are never even called, destructor is only once in the very end